# what does the token ! mean in this context (alongside a binding)?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I guess this mean no something but I'm not sure and besides I don't get what does it mean in the loop context

This a function looping through an array of objects.

```
function journalEvents(journal) {
let events = [];
   for (let entry of journal) {
     for (let event of entry.events) {
       if (!events.includes(event)) {
         events.push(event);
       }
} }
   return events;
 }
```

I outputs 4 numbers, getting a pattern in the data

Comment: Its just `Logical NOT (!)` so when its false it makes it true. And `includes` return `boolean`

Comment: if events does not include event

Comment: Thanks Shubh. So let ask you something. Does this mean:  wether events DON'T include a particular event (if an event is not already stored in the binding events) push it into events?

Comment: Please see the answer @paulocleon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`includes` is a boolean function: it return true weather the element `event` does exist in `events` list. The `!` operator juust reverse the returning value (i.e. you get false if it returns true, and true otherwise).

Comment: So, why just script it like: `if (events.includes(event)) {events.push(event);}` ? Or why do I need to get false when true is returned?

Comment: I think a got it: whether some event is NOT in events push it into events. Thanks everybody, this is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a logical "not" operator.

It basically means "take the opposite of this boolean". When the boolean after it is true, it returns false, and vise versa.

In your context, the if statement there means "if event isn't in events". This prevents the code from adding the same event to the "events" array twice.

You can read more on logical operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)!